# Load css code into textarea add 1 at the last line

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, textarea

I am loading the Content of my css file into my textarea, but somehow the textarea does not Show it correctly. The first and last line or incorrect.

For instance I am loading something like this:

```
.notifications {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}

...

.notifications > div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

But the textarea Formats it like this:

```
                .notifications {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.notifications > div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}1
```

Somehow lots of spaces are added to the first line and a "1" is added to the last line. If I remove the spaces and the "1" in the textarea and save it I sent following "payload":

```
"""
.notifications {\n
  position: fixed;\n
  z-index: 9999;\n
}\n
\n
/* Positioning */\n
.notifications.top-right {\n
  right: 10px;\n
  top: 25px;\n
}\n
\n
.notifications.top-left {\n
  left: 10px;\n
  top: 25px;\n
}\n
\n
.notifications.bottom-left {\n
  left: 10px;\n
  bottom: 25px;\n
}\n
\n
.notifications.bottom-right {\n
  right: 10px;\n
  bottom: 25px;\n
}\n
\n
/* Notification Element */\n
.notifications > div {\n
  position: relative;\n
  margin: 5px 0px;\n
}
"""
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" class="js-public-css" name="public_css">
        {{ include resource_path("/{$file}") }}
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" class="js-css-file-name" value="{{ $fileValue }}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success js-update-css-file-btn">
        Speichern
    </button>
</div>
```

And this is the js:

```
    $('.js-update-css-file-btn').click(function () {
        const content = $(this).prev().prev().html();
        const file = $(this).prev(".js-css-file-name").val();
        // console.log("content"+content);
        // console.log("file"+file);
        axios.post('brand/update', {
            file: file,
            content: content
        })
        .then((response) => {
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        })
    })
```

I don't have an idea why this is Happening.

Comment: can you also post the html and js for your issue

Comment: @user1579234 added

Comment: i dont see notifications style being used in html or anywhere else. i cant reproduce your issue without that.

Comment: @user1579234 the stil is not important it is just an example, Nothing to do with the css classes

Answer (score 0):

You do get spaces into your textarea because you do have spaces between your `textarea` tags in HTML, so you need to put them next to each other (`<textarea>...</textarea>`).

The 1 you are getting is probably because your Axios query is dealing with your CSS content like it was JSON. Set your query format header to plain text.